# AngularJS : passing model value from ng-repeat to ng-include to a directive using "=" in scope fails

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have the following code in my homepage

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in list" ng-bind-html-unsafe="item.Content" ng-include="item.Template" > </li>
</ul>
```

the value of item.template is *template1*  and item also has an attribute as item.WebServicePath which has the value

```
"http://.../....htm"
```

and template1 has:-

```
<directive1 s-web-service-path="{{item.WebServicePath}}" >        


</directive1 >
```

my directive1:-

```
directive("directive1", function ($http) {

try {
return {
    restrict: "E",

    transclude: true,
    scope: {


        sWebServicePath: "@"
    },

    template: "<div> {{sWebServicePath}}</div>",  -- this gets rendered with expected value

    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var request = {};

        $http({ method: "POST", url: attrs.sWebServicePath, data: request }).
        success(function (data, status) {
            scope.response = data;
        }).
        error(function (data, status) {
            alert("Service Call Error");
        })
    }
}

}

catch (e) {
alert(e);

}

});
```

but **attrs.sWebServicePath** is said as undefined  this shudnt be the case i have seen egghead videos and this is the exact same way he does it only difference is that item.sWebServicePath   is defined in $scope but in my case *item* is being generated during ng-repeat iteration so would this necessarily fail?  but in directive template where i use binding ie {{}}  i get the correct value rendered   why cant i access it via attrs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dynamic value of `sWebServicePath` hasn't been assigned at the time the link function is called.

Wrap the $http call in a $watch.

```
directive("directive1", function ($http) {

try {
return {
    restrict: "E",

    transclude: true,
    scope: {


        sWebServicePath: "@"
    },

    template: "<div> {{sWebServicePath}}</div>",  -- this gets rendered with expected value

    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var request = {};

        scope.$watch('sWebServicePath', function(newVal) {
          if (newVal) {
            $http({ method: "POST", url: newVal, data: request }).
              success(function (data, status) {
                  scope.response = data;
              }).
              error(function (data, status) {
                  alert("Service Call Error");
              })
            });
          }
    }
}

}

catch (e) {
alert(e);

}

});
```

Comment: i will verify and get back... but it will be very helpful if you can explain a bit more it will be very appreciable and helpful to me... i mean just the execution flow and how $watch is working here? thanks!

Comment: [Here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch) are the details of $watch.  Basically $watch is notification hook into the digest cycle of angular.  Anytime the "watched" value changes the function is executed.